# ubuntu 16.04 wifi too slow but works fine with usb wifi

Tags: wireless

on hp laptop, internet with wifi randomly get slower.
Sometimes its perfect but sometime get too slow to open a page.

But when it get slower, I tried with usb wifi, it was working fine.

Anyone can help that whats happening

**result from lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: @pomsky I edited question with result of lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 (when usb adapter removed)

Comment: There is [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772528/wifi-dropping-at-random-times-bcm43142) with an answer. You may try the fix provided, but proceed with caution. Someone said after applying the fix, wireless stopped working altogether.